# How to copy table data from remote server to Local server in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, synchronization

I am trying to copy all table data from server to my local database, like

```
INSERT INTO [.\SQLEXPRESS].[Mydatabase]..MYTable
   SELECT * 
   FROM [www.MYSite.com].[Mydatabase]..MYTable
```

`www.MYSite.com` having `SQL LOGIN ID XYZ` AND `PASSWORD 1234`

but I get an error:

> Could not find server 'www.MYSite.com' in sys.servers.
>   Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary,
>   execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

I want to copy all the data from `Mytable` of `www.MYSite.com` to `Mytable` of `.\SQLExpress`.

How to resolve it? Please help.

**Update :**

I am using **Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0** to sync all data from `www.MYSite.com` to `.\SQLExpress` and vice versa, but in a one condition I want to copy data from `www.MYSite.com` to `.\SQLExpress` without sync framework

Please Note I am passing those SQL Statement using C#..

Comment: You have create linked servers

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar No Sir, I am using Sync Framework 2.0 to Sync All Data from server to Client and voice versa, but in a one condition i want to copy data from server to client without sync framework

Comment: I think http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854%28v=sql.110%29.aspx (Sync Framework 2.0 ) is Different thing You should use Linked servers when you have to access like this (as you specified in question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below information will help you:
Using SQL Server Management Tools you can use the [Import Feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx).

1. Connect to your SQL instance server.
2. Select your database schema.
3. Right click Tasks > Import.
4. and follow wizard instructions.

[image]

Comment: And how to use with C#

Comment: to do in C# you need to write a hard code to meet your needs. 
the best practices is to use one of the following methods: 
1. Using Import Feature in SSMS. 
2. Using replication feature. 
3. or using the SQL Integration Services.

Answer (score 2):

When you specify a database on another server, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [www.MYSite.com].[Mydatabase]..MYTable
```

... the server name needs to be one that the database server was previously configured to recognize.  It needs to be in the system table `sys.servers`.

So, you need to configure your SQLExpress instance to "know about" that server.

You can do this in code, with the stored procedure `sp_addlinkedserver`.  You can learn more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx).

Or, you can do it through SSMS:

[image: partial screen shot]