# How to copy data from server table to client table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to copy data from Server table to my client table.

I now to copy data from client table to client table 
like

```
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM oldTable
```

as well as I also know how to copy data from Server table to my client table using linked server using SSMS, but I want to copy data using C# codes.

similar question :

[How to copy table data from remote server to Local server in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697423/how-to-copy-table-data-from-remote-server-to-local-server-in-sql-server-2008)

any idea ??

Edit :

Now I am trying

1. Open Remote server connection  AS Con1
2. `SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM oldTable`
3. Open Client connection As Con2
4. `INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3) Values (Con1.column1,Con1.column2,Con1.column3)`

Comment: Seems like data migration, why not try exporting data from server and import again in client??

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) class to efficiently copy data from one table on a SQL Server instance into another table on another SQL Server instance.

Here you have the simplest code to do that:

```
using (var sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(SourceConnectionString))
using (var sourceCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SourceTable", sourceConnection))
using (var targetConnection = new SqlConnection(TargetConnectionString))
using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(targetConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, null)) 
{
    bcp.DestinationTableName = "TargetTable";
    sourceConnection.Open();
    targetConnection.Open();
    using (var sourceReader = sourceCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        bcp.WriteToServer(sourceReader);
    }
}
```

You might need to set other [`SqlBulkCopyOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) such as `KeepIdentity`. You also might need to set up column mappings if table structure are different.